# Show hide div inside parent div

Tags: javascript, html, show-hide

There are couple of child divs in a parent div. I want to show/hide a particular child.

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child0">Text here</div>
    <div id="child1">Text here</div>
</div>
```

I want on mouse over div id="parent" to show hide div id=child0, everything else in parent div stays the same (visible).

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: Correction: There are couple of divs child in parrent div. I want to show hide particular child                                     <div id="parent">
    <div="child">Text here</div>
<div id="parent">
    <div="child0">Text here</div>
    <div="child1">Text here</div>
</div>.                                                                 I want on mouse over div id="parrent" to show hide div id=child0, everithing else in parrent div stays the same(visable).

Comment: I just tried your css solution and it is not working.

Comment: What i wont to acomplish should be simple. There is a couple divs in wrapper div, with images and text and one div representing button function. I wont the button div to appear on mouse over wrapper div.

Comment: Try _my_ answer - I even included a link to a live working version. Make sure you provide a mouse-free alternative method of doing whatever that button is supposed to do so that you cater to people who can't/don't use a mouse. (People with physical disabilities, _everyone_ using a phone/tablet device, etc.)

Answer (score 6):

You can do it all with CSS. Assuming this HTML:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child0">Child0 Text here</div>
    <div id="child1">Child1 Text here</div>
</div>
```

You can add something like this CSS:

```
#child0 {
   display: none;
}

#parent:hover #child0 {
   display: block;
}
```

See it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/QjeUq/

Comment: +1 for solving the problem using CSS. Correct me if I am wrong, but I seem to remember that the `:hover` pseudo selector applies to `a` elements in those old, annoying IE installations that just will not die. Depending on your target audience this may or may not be a problem.

Comment: @JørnSchou-Rode - yes, `:hover` only works with `a` elements in IE6. It works with other elements from IE7 onwards.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`CSS`:

```
.outer_wrapper_class .inner_wrapper_class {
    display: none;
}
.outer_wrapper_class:hover .inner_wrapper_class {
    display: block;
}
```

`HTML`:

```
<div class='outer_wrapper_class'>
    <!-- HOVERABLE CONTENT HERE -->
    <div class='inner_wrapper_class'>
    <!-- HIDE/SHOW CONTENT HERE -->
    </div>
    <!-- HOVERABLE CONTENT CAN ALSO BE HERE -->
</div>
```

Comment: But how can you mouseover a div that is already hidden with `display:none`?

Comment: Sorry about that. I'm a little sloppy with responses when I'm tired. The edit should be better.